Why does UART1 interrupt does not work in STM32F100 (KEIL)
There is a simple code where an external interrupt from a button sends “1” via USART1, and when zero arrives from the same UART, the LEDs go out. I use KEIL 5 to compile.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stm32f10x.h>
 
#define BLUE_LED_ON GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BS8
#define GREEN_LED_ON GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BS9
#define BLUE_LED_OFF GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BR8
#define GREEN_LED_OFF GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BR9
 
void EXTI0_IRQHandler (void);
void USART1_IRQHandler (void);
void Button_Interrupt_Init (void);
void Led_Init (void);
void UART_Init (void);
 
int main (void)
{//USART1 TX-PA9 RX-PA10
    SystemInit();
    Button_Interrupt_Init();
    UART_Init();
    Led_Init();
        
    while(1){}
}
 
void Button_Interrupt_Init (void)
{
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN;
    AFIO->EXTICR[0] |= AFIO_EXTICR1_EXTI0_PA;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;
    
    __enable_irq();
    EXTI->PR |= EXTI_PR_PR0;
    EXTI->RTSR |= EXTI_RTSR_TR0;
    EXTI->IMR |= EXTI_IMR_MR0;
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn); 
}
void Led_Init (void)
{
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPCEN;
    GPIOC->CRH = GPIO_CRH_MODE8|GPIO_CRH_MODE9;
    BLUE_LED_ON;
    GREEN_LED_ON;
    for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
    BLUE_LED_OFF;
    GREEN_LED_OFF;
    for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
    BLUE_LED_ON;
    GREEN_LED_ON;
    for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
    BLUE_LED_OFF;
    GREEN_LED_OFF;
    for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
    BLUE_LED_ON;
    GREEN_LED_ON;
    for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
    BLUE_LED_OFF;
    GREEN_LED_OFF;
    for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
}
void UART_Init (void)
{
//CLEAN CNF AND MODE and SET 1011 - alternative push/pull
    GPIOA->CRH &= ~(GPIO_CRH_CNF9|GPIO_CRH_CNF10|GPIO_CRH_MODE9|GPIO_CRH_MODE10);
    GPIOA->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_MODE9|GPIO_CRH_CNF9_1|GPIO_CRH_MODE10|GPIO_CRH_CNF10_1;
    
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN;
    USART1->BRR = 0x4E2;
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE|USART_CR1_TE|USART_CR1_RE;
    USART1->CR1 &= ~(USART_CR1_M|USART_CR1_PCE);
    USART1->CR2 &= ~(USART_CR2_STOP);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
}   
void USART1_IRQHandler (void)
{
        GREEN_LED_ON;
        BLUE_LED_ON;
    if(USART1->SR & USART_SR_RXNE)                                                                                                                              // Check is 'RX not empty' bit set -> data is in UART->DR
    {
        uint8_t RXc = (uint8_t)(USART1->DR&0xFF);                                                                   // put symbol from UART->DR in RXc variable
        switch(RXc)                                                                                                                                                             // Symbol-dependent cases
        {
            case '0':
                GREEN_LED_OFF;
            break;
            default:
                BLUE_LED_OFF;
            break;
        }
    }
NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_IRQn);                                                                                                                  // Clear pending bit from UART1 interrupt
}
 
void EXTI0_IRQHandler (void)
{
    USART1->DR = 1; 
    EXTI->PR |= EXTI_PR_PR0;
}

The problem is that when the button is pressed, "1" comes to the terminal and everything is ok, but when I try to send a character from the terminal to the microcontroller, the MCU does not enter the interrupt when. GREEN_LED_ON and BLUE_LED_ON should be ON when MCU entering an interrupt, but nothing happens.
I tried to make an STM32CUBEIDE project with USART1 initialization, just add UART_Init (the same as above but this one is without pin configurations) and USART1_IRQHandler functions in auto-generated code. CUBEIDE code is here (without "user code begin/end etc things"):
#include "main.h"

#define BLUE_LED_ON GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BS8
#define GREEN_LED_ON GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BS9
#define BLUE_LED_OFF GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BR8
#define GREEN_LED_OFF GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BR9

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

void UART_Init (void);
void USART1_IRQHandler (void);

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);

int main(void)
{


  HAL_Init();


  SystemClock_Config();


  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  UART_Init();
  GREEN_LED_ON;
  BLUE_LED_ON;



  while (1)
  {

  }

}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

 
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL3;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

 
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{


  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC8 PC9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
void UART_Init (void)
{
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE|USART_CR1_TE|USART_CR1_RE;
    USART1->CR1 &= ~(USART_CR1_M|USART_CR1_PCE);
    USART1->CR2 &= ~(USART_CR2_STOP);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
}
void USART1_IRQHandler (void)
{
    if(USART1->SR & USART_SR_RXNE)                                                                                                                              // Check is 'RX not empty' bit set -> data is in UART->DR
    {
        uint8_t RXc = (uint8_t)(USART1->DR&0xFF);                                                                   // put symbol from UART->DR in RXc variable
        switch(RXc)                                                                                                                                                             // Symbol-dependent cases
        {
            case '0':
                GREEN_LED_OFF;
            break;
            case '1':
                BLUE_LED_OFF;
            break;
            default:
                BLUE_LED_ON;
                GREEN_LED_ON;
            break;
        }
    }
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_IRQn);                                                                                                                  // Clear pending bit from UART1 interrupt
}

void Error_Handler(void)
{
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

And this code works great! I receive all the messages from the terminal and the code processes them as needed.
The only difference between these codes that I noticed is the lack of initialization of contacts PA9 and PA10 (responsible for USART) in the CUBE code.
So the questions is:

What could be the KEIL code problem? (i think the problem is close to USART-pin configuration)
Is there USART pin (PA9/PA10) configuration in CUBE code? Where HAL does this configuration?

Thank you!
A few clarifications for understanding:

In KEIL code EXTI0_IRQHandler (Button interrupt) works well, USART1_IRQHandler doesn't work and i see it because GREEN_LED_ON and BLUE_LED_ON does not work.
In CUBE code USART1_IRQHandler works well, but i do not see USART pin configuration in HAL code.


After configuring everything and before you while(1) in your Keil project, trigger a UART interrupt through software (a one-liner like NVIC->SWI = IRQnumber;). You should enter interrupt handler upon doing that. This will allow you to check if the interrupt is properly configured.

Additional note:     NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_IRQn);                                                                                                                  // Clear pending bit from UART1 interrupt you don't need this line at the end of interrupt handler. Interrupt pending flag is cleared in the NVIC automatically. You can safely remove it. You only need to clear flags inside the peripheral, but not inside NVIC.

@Ilya Thank's for your answers! I have fixed the problem, but i dont clearly underatand hyw my fix works. I just delited GPIO configurations for PA10 (UART RX) and now i can receive and transmit anything i want. But i still dont understand why it works, PA10 without configurations is just floating imput (because of reset state). Is UART RX shouldn't be configerated as alternate function? Now i see that alternate function is possible only for output mode and RX pin should be configured as imput but it's still strange for me

You can check using debug mode. Pause the program when all configuration is done (do it for working and not working configuration), and check GPIO mode register and alternate function register. It could be something in your program that reconfigures the pin.

@Ilya there are no GPIO mode and GPIO alter func registers in stm32f100, this functions configured in GPIO CRH and CRL registers.  And manual says there is no way to set pin as alter func imput mode. I've found some videos on YT and people says that is correct - UART RX should be configured as imput Hi-Z state.

You have completely missed my point. My point was not to tell you the exact registers. My point was "use a debugger and compare configs of working and non-working code". I'm trying to make you find what exactly you did wrong. You will learn a lot more from doing that.

@Ilya thanks for your help! I've used debugger and i t helped me to understand that guys from YT were right, PA10 (RX) should be configured as input without alternate func.

When you work with STM32F100, you can't set pin as alternate function INPUT (refere to manual, CRH and CRL registers) so configure PA10 (UART RX) as input. In my case i just delited PA10 configurations in UART_Init function in KEIL code (PA10 is floating input in reset state)
